# Softwares to determine semi-simple types of Lie algebras generated over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ by a set of matrices

Tags: lie-algebras, math-software, gap, semisimple-lie-algebras

I wish to determine the type of Lie algebra generated over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ by a set of square matrices with irrational elements. I've been using `GAP` and it is quite good at determining the type of Lie algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$, which seems to work fine when all the matrix elements are rational numbers. However, when the matrices contain irrational numbers like $\sqrt{2}$ or $\sqrt{3}$, although I can manage to get a Lie algebra over cyclotomic numbers, the function `SemiSimpleType` does not work with Lie algebras over cyclotomic numbers. Therefore I wish to know:

Is there a way of doing this with `GAP`? If not, are there any other softwares which can do this?

Comment: Have you tried to represent over the rationals? If you can post an example I can show you how to do this.

Comment: @ahulpke Thanks! I've tried this, but when a matrix contains say both $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$, the result over $\mathbb{Q}$ v.s. over $\mathbb{R}$ would be different, right? Or is there a systematic way to deduce the result over $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: If you go from Q to R the type should stay the same. So you want to consider the Lie algebra as one over Q, which you can do by rationalizing the matrices (at the cost of increasing the dimension)

Comment: @ahulpke Thanks! Here is the example I am working on using ```GAP```: ```nplus:= [ [0,-1/Sqrt(2),0,1], [0,0,-1/Sqrt(2),0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,1/Sqrt(3),0] ];
nminus:= [ [0,0,0,0], [1/Sqrt(2),0,0,0], [0,1/Sqrt(2),0,1], [1/Sqrt(3),0,0,0] ];
n3:= [ [1/Sqrt(2),0,0,0], [0,0,0,1], [0,0,-1/Sqrt(2),0], [0,-1/Sqrt(3),0,0] ];``` The result I got over $\mathbb{Q}$ is 8 copies of $A_1$. Based on this result, what should I expect to get over $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to rationalize the matrices -- increase the dimension but get rational matrices.

```
gap> mats:=[nplus,nminus,n3];;
gap> B:=Basis(CF(24));
CanonicalBasis( CF(24) )
gap> new:=List(mats,x->BlownUpMat(B,x));;
gap> Length(new[1]);
32
```

So now you have $32\times32$ matrices, but the rational algebras spanned by them are isomorphic, and there. is no ambiguity what the rational algebra spanned by the new matrices should be:

```
gap> a:=LieAlgebra(Rationals,new);
<Lie algebra over Rationals, with 3 generators>
gap> SemiSimpleType(a);
"A1 A1 A1 A1 A1 A1 A1 A1"
```

You could do a rational base change here to expose the structure of eight copies of $A_1$. If you reduce this base change back down to $Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ you would get the same decomposition there (or over cyclotomics), thus it is the same.

Added in response to the comment:

Why is the R-structure the same as the Q-structure: The R-algebra contains the Q-algebra, we just extend the set of coefficients, but it does not change the multiplicative structure (multiplication of basis elements) of the algebra. A direct sum decomposition of the Q-algebra thus extends to a decomposition of the R-algebra, and any Q-basis of the Q-algebra will be am R-basis of the R-algebra.
Now consider one summand: If it is $A_1$, it means we can find a Q-basis, such that the basis vectors multiply in a certain pattern. This will extend to R, and thus the R-type is the same.

Comment: Thanks! I think we got same results, which makes sense because they are both Lie algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$. However I am interested in what this Lie algebra is over $\mathbb{R}$. What can we say about this?

Comment: Over $\R$ it will be 8 copies of $A_1(\R)$ -- do the rational base change to the copies of $A_1$ and then extend coefficients.

Comment: This is not what I need. I want to know what is the Lie algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ before doing the rational basis change.

Comment: The structure over $\R$ is the same kind. I have added a remark.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by the same kind? Without going to the rational basis, I know  the three $n$ matrices are $4\times 4$. Therefore the Lie algebra it generates over $\mathbb{R}$ is at most rank $4$, and therefore cannot be eight copies of $A_1$.

Comment: With the quadupling diue to the Galois group, presumably just two copies of $A_1$. This would be consistent with dimension 6 over the cyclotomics.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I need. Can I understand the quadrupling as generated by $1$, $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{6}$?

Comment: Yes -- the dimension of the field over the rationals.

Comment: What if the matrix elements are transcendental numbers?

Comment: I have no idea on transcendental elements.